# Dojo ItemFileWriteStore not reading JSON server file

Tags: json, dojo

I am using Dojo and it's dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore module to read a JSON data file on my local server. In my .js file I have

```
var myDataStore = new ItemFileWriteStore({
    url: "app/data/mydata.json",
    handleAs: "json",
    clearOnClose: true,
    urlPreventCache: true
})
```

This is located in the postCreate function for my return declare function... so:

```
 define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "com/cayuse/base/_widget",
    "dojo/text!./templates/myform.html",
    ...    
    "dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
    "dojo/store/DataStore",
    "dojo/store/Observable",
    "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
    function(declare, widget, template, ..., ItemFileWriteStore, DataStore, 
        Observable, ObjectStore){
        return declare("app.myform", widget, {
            templateString: template,

            postCreate: function(){

                domConstruct.create("link",{
                    type: "text/css",
                    rel: "stylesheet",
                    href: require.toUrl('dojox/form/resources/CheckedMultiSelect.css')
                }, document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);

                // data store
                var myDataStore = new ItemFileWriteStore({
                    url: "app/data/mydata.json",
                    handleAs: "json",
                    clearOnClose: true,
                    urlPreventCache: true
                })
                console.log(myDataStore);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

I can change the data store access from what you see above using IFWS method to

```
var myDataStore = dojo.xhrGet({
    url: "app/data/mydata.json",
    handleAs: "json",
    load: function(data, ioArgs){
         console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

and it finds the file with no problems.

This is so bizarre! Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

UPDATED: 
Here is the data in the file I am reading. I believe it conforms to the JSON format. Let me know if not. xhrGet reads it fine.

```
{ "identifier": "id",
    "label": "firstName",
    "items":[
     {"id":"0","firstName":"Robert","website":"www.barker.com","email":"robert@barker.com","bday":"1928-08-09","color":"Blue","toolkits":["Dojo","Moo"],"sendEmail":["on"],"format":"HTML"},
     {"id":"1","firstName":"Vanna","website":"www.white.com","email":"vanna@white.com","bday":"1968-07-23","color":"Green","toolkits":["Dojo","jQuery"],"sendEmail":["off"],"format":"Text"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ItemFileWriteStore requires your data being structured into something like this:

```
{ identifier: 'abbr',
  label: 'name',
  items: [
    { abbr:'ec', name:'Ecuador',           capital:'Quito' },
    { abbr:'eg', name:'Egypt',             capital:'Cairo' },
    { abbr:'sv', name:'El Salvador',       capital:'San Salvador' },
    { abbr:'gq', name:'Equatorial Guinea', capital:'Malabo' },
    { abbr:'er', name:'Eritrea',           capital:'Asmara' },
    { abbr:'ee', name:'Estonia',           capital:'Tallinn' },
    { abbr:'et', name:'Ethiopia',          capital:'Addis Ababa' }
]}
```

That is 'identifier' being your "ID" field, 'label' being your "label" field and then all your objects inside an array called "items".

You can check it out here [in ItemFileWriteStore's documentation](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore). If you don't have your JSON data structured like that it's possible that you may end up reading your file with the IFWS and actually not reading any data.

There are other store implementations in dojo 1.7 that don't require such structure, e.g. [Memory](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/Memory.html) Store that you can combine with other file reading techniques to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response eburgos. I should have posted my file data. It does conform to that structure. I will add that to my post.

One thing that puzzles me is that I have seen some on this forum state that the attributes and values both must be quoted for true JSON format. I've tried both ways but my problem is that the file is not being fetched. I look in Firebug at the Net XHR activity and the file is never touched.  And besides, when I do use dojo xhrGet it reads the same file just fine. It's really wierd, this problem I have.

Comment: So when the Firebug Net XHR activity does no requests?

Answer (score 0):

Try using dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore for reading 
json data files, instead of dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore.

Note that dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore is used for writting json data.

Comment: I thought ItemFileWriteStore includes the functionality of ItemFileReadStore as well?  If you are correct and it makes a difference, then that would be odd that an object that has a subset of IFWS works but not IFWS itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is EXACTLY as you posted it above then the interpreter might not like the fact that you omitted the semicolon from the ItemFileWriteStore assignment.  Try adding the ';' as below:

```
            // data store
            var myDataStore = new ItemFileWriteStore({
                url: "app/data/mydata.json",
                handleAs: "json",
                clearOnClose: true,
                urlPreventCache: true
            });
            console.log(myDataStore);
```